Are there any Japanese surnames referring to the beech tree?
I am interested to know whether any habitational surnames (or toponyms that could viably be used as surnames) in Japan are related to the Japanese beech tree (ぶな). I have found surname etymologies difficult to find online.
Forenames have been easier to find; finding a surname related to hunting or bowmanship yielded 勇 (Isamu, "brave"). Still, the question of surnames/toponyms related to the beech tree has eluded me!

The kanji is apparently 橅, if that helps.

You have asked about "etymology", but I presume you are interested in names which include the name for "beech". After all, it is not in practice going to be possible to investigate exactly how it came about that a certain person got a certain name.
According to Japanese Wikipedia there are three ways of writing buna: 橅・山毛欅・椈. (The three character one brings up lots of pages in Chinese, so I guess that is the Chinese name. My input system offers 山毛欅 and 椈, where my (real) Nelson gives 橅 and 山毛欅 only.)
My 難読姓氏辞典 lists only 橅木, for which it gives the readings kafuraki, kaburaki, and kaburagi.
My 難読地名辞典 lists:

山毛欅ヶ平山 bunagatairayama　新潟県
山毛欅さ沢山 bunazawayama　福島県
山毛欅潰山 bunakuzureyama　山形県
椈森 bunamori　秋田県

These are all natural feature names (as opposed to administrative names), and perhaps not surprisingly they are all from northern Honshu.
Hope this helps - more details on request.

Sincere thanks for your answer! This is excellently informative. Thanks again.
